# American vs. British English: meaning of "One hundred and fifty"

Tags: american-english, british-english, numbers, speech, transatlantic-differences

I've noticed that Americans do not say "and" when speaking numbers: for example, 150 would be pronounced "one hundred fifty".

I and most other British-English speakers would pronounce it "one hundred and fifty".

I've seen a few different arguments on the net about which is "better", and something that is often asserted on the American side is that the "and" represents a decimal point - so "one hundred and fifty" would be interpreted as 100.50.

This struck me as odd, since although I see a lot of American movies and TV, I don't think I've ever heard anyone actually do this.

So my question: is this "and = decimal point" actually used in the USA, and can anyone cite some examples (maybe on youtube?)?

Comment: "And" for the decimal seems to me common when speaking of money, but not so common as far as i can tell in other contexts.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't heard this usage either. (I'm also a Brit.)

Comment: i'd say one fiddy

Comment: @Noldorin: Which usage haven't you heard? "One hundred and fifty" used for 150, or it being taken to mean 100.50? I assume you meant the latter, and the former is standard in British English. [At least, it's so in India... 150 is always *"hun redun fifty"*. :-)]

Comment: @Shreevatsar: The latter of course, where 'and' represents the decimal point. I wouldn't be a Brit if I didn't understand the first heh. Also, note that although Indian English descends from British English, it exhibits many dialectical differences these days.

Comment: In darts you need the 'and' to give the score a more pleasing rhythm. One hundred and eighty!

Comment: @John: Haha, this is true. Not sure Americans play darts though really, or at least aren't quite so fascinated with it as us Brits!

Comment: The 50 after the decimal point isn't "fifty", it's "five zero".

Comment: I was watching the Australian movie *Fatty Finn* the other day.  Set in the 1930s, when Australia used pounds, shillings and pence.  Fatty asks the pawnshop owner the price of the crystal set he wants.  Afterward Fatty moans: "Seventeen and six?  Where am I supposed to get seventeen and six, mister?"

Comment: Similar question here; http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/how-do-you-correctly-say-large-numbers

Comment: I agree, Blorgbeard. The  "and = decimal point" is odd. Like Noldorin, I haven't this usage. It doesn't have that meaning, in the UK.

Comment: I know South African English is very similar to USA-English, but we don't say `one hundred fifty`, instead we say (the same as Brits), `one hundred and fifty`. When talking about money, I say `one hundred and fifty Pounds` or `one hundred Pounds fifty`.

Comment: As a hardcore American, I've never heard "and" used in the decimal point sense. We say "point." If someone said "one hundred and fifty," I would most definitely interpret that as 150, not 100.50; this goes for all contexts.

Comment: The only place where `and` = `decimal point`, in my experience, is when writing checks. It's used on the line where the amount is spelled as words, e.g. "One hundred and 75/100"

Comment: No one notices the "and."  It's just faster to not say it.

Answer (score 36):

When I learned this “rule” (in first grade, I believe), it was explained that *and* separates the whole part from the fractional part: 2⅔=*two and two thirds*. The word *and* would only represent the decimal point in decimal numbers when they are read out in the formal “fractional” reading of decimals, as 2.3=*two and three tenths*, or 1.75=*one and seventy-five one-hundredths*. That is, according to this rule, **one hundred and fifty* is ungrammatical because, if it is supposed to mean 150, it should be *one hundred fifty*, and if it is supposed to be mean 100.50, it should be *one hundred and fifty one-hundredths*. The rationale behind the rule is that you should only have one *and* in a phrase, so if the number were 403⅞, you wouldn’t say *four hundred **and** three **and** seven eighths*.

Of course, most of the time the decimal point is read as *point*: 2.3=*two point three*; 1.75=*one point seven five* or *one point seventy-five*; 100.50=*one hundred point five zero*, *one hundred point five oh*, or *one hundred point fifty*. The fractional reading of decimal numbers also starts to become a bit ridiculous if there are more than three digits after the decimal point: nobody would say 3.14159265=*three and fourteen million one hundred fifty-nine thousand two hundred sixty-five one hundred millionths*.

As you have undoubtedly observed, many Americans don’t follow the rule about *and* only being used to separate whole and fractional parts, and insert *and* just before the units of a number less than one hundred, although the forms without *and* are quite common too.

457 *four hundred fifty-seven* or *four hundred and fifty-seven*
2001 *two thousand one* or *two thousand and one*
1,000,001 *one million one* or *one million and one*

Comment: I don't believe I have *ever* heard anybody say "one and seventy-five one-hundredths" and the like. The only place I have encountered it is in American fiction: I noticed it in some early Heinlein stories, and thought it bizarre. It sounds as if it was actually taught, then.

Comment: FWIW, this was the rule I was taught in primary school as well.

Comment: Amazing that teachers feel they have so much time to burn on such obscurities. Or were you in the fast stream?  
I can't think of one single incident of being misunderstood using 'xxx and xx' format or more than one 'and' in a  phrase, in over 26 years in international business.

Comment: If the text read "1.75", in my experience people almost always read that "one point seven five" or sometimes "one point seventy-five". If the text reads "1 75/100", then people read it "one and seventy-five hundredths".

Comment: @nohat IMHO "one hundred and one and five tenths" makes perfect sense and "one hundred one and five tenths" feels like is missing an "and".  I don't get the rule about not having more than one "and".  Could be my British ear but I do feel there is a real difference between typical British and American usage when it comes to writing out numbers.

Comment: "there is a real difference between typical British and American usage" of English in general. How this site makes any sense whatsoever after about seven years of not requiring a dialect tag on every question is beyond me.

Answer (score 15):

I speak Canadian English and over here I'd say both usages are common and nobody ever says "and" when they mean "decimal" or "point".

As far as nohat's answer, where the "rule" is that you can only use and for fractional parts, I've never been taught that rule as far as I can recall.

Comment: This time Mr.S&N are on the same page. I've started to call 'American English' 'Canadian English', BTW, since they're almost identical. I've never heard anyone, from anywhere, use 'and' when they mean decimal or point. And I attend many international scientific conferences where speakers from everywhere talk about numbers. There is no such rule, nohat. Sorry. Maybe that's why no one has observed Americans following that rule? Just a wild guess.

Comment: @bev if you read my answer, you would see that I never claimed that anyone uses 'and' when they mean 'decimal' or 'point', but rather that in formal American English, you only use 'and' to separate the whole number part from the fractional part of a number—where the fractional part of the number is read *as a fraction*. The Wikipedia article on numerals supports these claims http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Fractions_and_decimals

Answer (score 14):

Instead of "I've never seen..." answers, how about some actual references?  Like this:

[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Numbers)

> When saying or writing out numbers, the British insert an and before the tens and units, as in one hundred and sixty-two or two thousand and three. In the United States it is considered correct to drop the and, as in one hundred sixty-two or two thousand three.

Comment: The quoted text is actually the best answer so far. I hear it both ways here in the USA. Neither is "considered incorrect".

Comment: @T.E.D.: I think you misinterpret "correct" there as meaning "the right thing to do". It actually means "valid", with no implication that any alternative is "not valid".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think if that had been the author's intent, they might have said "acceptable" rather than "correct". The latter suggests a preference, although it doesn't mean it's exclusive.

Comment: @Barmar: Even in the context of the actual text cited here, one can infer "correct" means "exclusively so", from the fact that US usage is being contrasted with UK usage (where dropping "and" is *not* correct, and is at best only tolerated as an "Americanism"). If you look at the rest of the section in the Wikipedia article, you'll see it's absolutely littered with terms like *usually, often, normally, more likely, frequently*, etc. Since it doesn't "hedge" the cited assertion as *"...in the US it is **also** considered correct..."*, I stand by my comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You seem to be contradicting yourself. Your first comment says it should not be interpreted as exclusive, now you say it should be.

Comment: @Barmar: Um - yeah! The first comment was made a long time ago, when I was doubtless adopting the position I'd have *liked* to be the case (that Americans are as tolerant of "British" practice as we perforce are in the opposite direction). I've since become increasingly convinced that US usage conventions are *on average* far more "dogmatic" than UK conventions, so I no longer stand by that first comment. You are correct, and my second comment backs you up. I won't ***delete*** the first comment, as it would make those following very confusing - but I certainly ***repudiate*** it now!

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, as an American, I've never heard the usage "one hundred and fifty" to mean 100.50 (or similar). I would say "a hundred fifty," or "one hundred and fifty" to mean 150, but not "one hundred fifty".

Even in dealing with currency I never hear *and* used to indicate a decimal unless the decimal is followed by the word *cents*.

IE: for $20.75:

'Twenty dollars and seventy-five cents' might be used, but 'Twenty seventy-five' would be more common.

Comment: Working with money seems to change the way the numbers are spoken.

Comment: Interesting that for 150 and 100.50 actual usage is the opposite of the purported "rule" would require. (This may vary by region; I would probably even take "a hundred fifty" as 100.50 rather than 150.)

Comment: I would expect the cashier at a supermarket to use the shorter form

Comment: Hundreds with additional units following are I think pronounced somewhat differently from those without.  If someone was counting out change and said "one hundre-duh an-duh fifty", I might be prone to interpret it as $100.50", but not if I heard "one hundreh-ndt fifty".  I suspect the "and" is included not for its literal meaning, but rather because it's easier to say a glottal stop followed by an alveolar stop (an "dn" followed by a "d" or "t") than two consecutive alveolar stops.

Comment: If you're counting, you don't count "One thousand *and* one, one thousand *and* two, ...". You count "One thousand one, one thousand two, ..." Putting in *and*s sounds weird, and imagine how much longer it'd take to count with all those *and*s.

Answer (score 6):

As an American, I've never heard of the 'and' indicating a decimal.  Except when writing a check (cheque).  In that case, when writing out the words, we use

```
One hundred fifty and no/100 for 150.00 
One hundred and 50/100 for 100.50
```

But, as you notice, the decimal parts are not spelled out.  As for spoken usage, both sound correct which probably means that both are in common usage.

Comment: It's a different topic, but I was bemused when I found that Americans wrote /100 for the cents, (or had it printed on their checks). This has never been customary in the UK.

Comment: Bemused? Why bemused? I'm not normally bemused when I learn something new.

Comment: That's because our checks print the second line as "____________ dollars", so you have to write the cents part as a fraction to make it grammatically correct.

Comment: On a British cheque, if it was a whole number of pounds, you would tend to write "One hundred and fifty pounds only"

Comment: @Neil, a lot of Americans also write "only" to indicate no change, or say "even", like: "twenty dollars even"

Comment: @Colin Hmm, it doesn't seem at all surprising to me that cheques in Britain would not be pre-printed with the words "dollars" and "cents", as last I heard, in Britain they use pounds and pence.

Comment: Pre-decimalization, saying either 100 and 73/100 pounds, or 100 and 73/240 pounds, would have been ridiculous. So I expect tradition is what keeps cheques in Britain from having "pounds" pre-printed on them.

Comment: @PeterShor: no, I don't think so. Pre-decimal, we used to write £5/7/6 for five pounds seven (shillings) and six(pence), and since 1971 we have written either £5.75 or some people write £5.75p. There has never been a tradition of writing money as a fraction /100, and I think most British people would be utterly confused if you presented an amount that way.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, what is "and no/100" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Pacerier, it's a way of indicating no decimal value, an even dollar amount.  It's kind of a mish-mash between English and math.  As check writing becomes less common, I imagine it will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday my five year old son answered a question with, "Three hundred and forty-four," which prompted my thirteen year old daughter to correct him, saying that he shouldn't say the "and" because that indicates that the number after "and" is a decimal or fraction. I told her that was crazy and I'd never heard that before. However, my wife agreed that my daughter was right. My wife received all of her education in Utah, as has my daughter so far. I went to kindergarten through third grade in Utah, but I went to fourth grade through the end of high school in California. I don't know if that has anything to do with our differing perspectives here, but I cannot ever remember having heard someone say "some number AND some other number" to indicate whole numbers followed by decimals. On the other hand, I can't remember ever having been taught that such a thing was correct or incorrect either. In terms of both my education and my life experience (mostly in Utah, California, Nevada, and Arizona), I have always understood that the word that denotes a decimal is the word "point." I have, however, heard the "and" separator for fractions and even for decimals, but only if the number is followed by "tenths" or "hundredths," etc.

Comment: I've always agreed with the "and" rule, but I've noticed it as often honored in the breach as in the observation.

Comment: Three hundred and forty-four hundredths.

Comment: @tchrist, but if someone says "three hundred and forty-four", is your natural inclination to assume that they must have forgotten to add "hundredths" or "eightieths" or similar? Or is your natural inclination to assume that they've inserted an "and" which is superfluous to your ears?

Comment: @tchrist: Suddenly, I see where this "rule" might have come from. If you say three hundred and fifty-four hundredths, is it 354/100, or 354 1/100? Somebody came up with the idea that you should leave the "and" out of "three hundred and fifty-four" to avoid this ambiguity, and somebody else completely misunderstood this. I don't believe anybody says *"three hundred and fifty-four"* to mean *"three hundred point fifty-four"*.

Comment: Oops. I meant 354/100 or 300 54/100 above.

Answer (score 2):

Within mathematics, two numerics associated with an "and" indicates summation; the common usage is "two and two is four" (2+2=4). (Note that mathematical sentences can include multiple "and"s; eg two and two and two is six (2+2+2=6).) So "one-hundred and fifty" would be 100 + 50 where "one-hundred fifty" would be 150. That being said, "one-hundred and fifty thousand" is commonly interpreted as 150,000, not 100 + 50,000. As such, it was my understanding that the "and" usage be limited as confusion can and does occur.

Comment: Curiously, Danny Kaye agrees differently than you do: *Two and two **are** four. /
Four and four **are** eight. /
Eight and eight **are** sixteen. /
Sixteen and sixteen **are** thirty-two. /
Inchworm, inchworm, /
Measuring the marigold, /
You and your arithmatic, /
You’ll probably go far. /
Inchworm, inchworm, /
Measuring the marigold, /
Seems to me you’d stop and see, /
How beautiful they are.*

Comment: @tchrist: All but one of the sites I found with the lyrics to the “Inchworm” (or “Inch Worm”) song, including [this one](http://kids.niehs.nih.gov/games/songs/childrens/inchwormmp3.htm) (at a **.gov** web site!), confirm my memory that the lyric is “measuring the marigolds” (plural). The fact that [angelfire](http://www.angelfire.com/film/dannykaye/Inchworm.htm) misspells “arithmetic” should make us question its accuracy.

Comment: @Scott Then listen to the song.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Canadian, and its common to drop the "hundred" as well, when pronouncing 150.  Most of the time I would say "one fifty", which is also how I would pronounce 1.50.  Just to make things even more confusing.

Comment: I think that's also common in British English.

Comment: Blorgbeard. Not very.

Comment: How would you pronounce the time "ten to two" ?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been here 14 years (from the UK) and dropping the *and* still sounds weird to my ear.  Try and imagine a commentator at a darts match shouting *“one hundred eighty”* instead of *“one hundred **and** eighty”*.  Just doesn’t have the same impact.  Try saying *“one three quarters”* (could be heard as ¾) vs. *“one **and** three quarters”* (clearly means 1 ¾).

I should add that I’ve never heard or considered using *and* as a decimal point.

Comment: "One three quarters" is clearly an incorrect way to say 1 ¾. Read nohat's answer: the reason American schoolchildren are taught to omit the "and" from numbers like "one hundred twenty-three" is precisely because the "and" is reserved for numbers like "one **and** three quarters".

Comment: No one omits the *and* with fractions, do they?  It just doesn’t sound right, as you rightly observe.

Comment: @Martha: So would you go the whole way with this system, and call say 1 000 000 001 'one billion one'? Have the book title changed to "One Thousand One Nights"?

Comment: Sir Richard Francis Burton's translation was entitled "The Book of the Thousand Nights and a Night".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: really, people need to read nohat's answer. Also, note how I said "... schoolchildren *are taught* to omit the 'and'...".

Comment: @Martha, I re-read nohat's answer and don't understand the "no more than one and" rule.  I think this is just a British/American English difference.

Answer (score 1):

I question the premise of your question. Americans often read 150 as "one hundred and fifty". When I was in elementary school I was taught that the "and" was superfluous and should be omitted, but lots of Americans say it.

As others have said, I've never heard anyone use "and" to indicate a decimal point by itself. An American typically reads a dollar amount, like "$100.50", as "one hundred dollars and fifty cents". For a non-monetary amount, like "100.50", Americans read that as "one hundred point five zero" or "one hundred point fifty".

Comment: Isn't 150 often read as "one hundred fifty" instead of "one hundred and fifty"?

Comment: Sometimes. That's what I mean by my second sentence. Sometimes it's read "one hundred and fifty", other times "one hundred fifty". I was taught that the "correct" way is without the "and", but if that's the rule, it is widely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Another scenario where the use of *and* in a series of numbers is unclear to me is in explaining temperatures in Fahrenheit, like for example *one hundred and three degrees*.

Though I generally avoid correcting people, when patients relay their temperature as such, I clarify their intended meaning.  For young or old, the intent can be 100.3 or 103.0, interestingly. This is unlikely an issue in other fields of work and in British or Canadian English.

Otherwise, I also was taught in grade school/primary school in Northern California that the use of *and* in a series of numbers indicated a decimal or preceded a fraction. For 150, both with and without *and* sound clear to me. In common speech, I would rarely be confused.

Comment: If you have clinical experience, far be it from me to gainsay you.  But to my ear, I could never imagine thinking that *“one hundred and three degrees”*  meant 100.3° instead of 103°.

Comment: I've definitely been told 100.3 when asking for clarification, but I agree with you my first impression when hearing this is 103.  To avoid ambiguity when stating the numbers, I would say "one-oh-three" for 103.0 and " one hundred point three" for 100.3.  I probably do overestimate how often this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I am from the UK, and I would just to clarify the reasoning why I would always use "One hundred and fifty".
The "and" splits the 2 numbers to avoid confusion that the "one hundred" may affect the "fifty" as in meaning "one hundred fifties" or in other words 100 * 50.
(This may be similar to the way I and other people from the UK pronounce "can't" as carnt because it is easier to distinguish)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Americans say one hundred and fifty as well. When we would say 100.50, we say "one hundred point five".

Never make claims about which you are not sure.

Comment: You’re right that this isn’t so cut-and-dried as other posters would have it. Sometimes North Americans says *one hundred and fifty-six* for 156; other times they say *a hundred fifty-six*.