# how to read numbers of 6 digit in formal english

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

How to say these two numbers:

112177

1. eleven hundrends thousands and twenty one hundren and seventy seven
2. one hundred and twelve thousands and one hundred seventy seven

the same for this number

196455

#### Update 1

I understood from the first comment that there is no good and wrong way. but the problem is that i have to make a presentation in front of native speakers, and i want to say the numbers in a way they understand nomrally

they are mainly from uk, london

#### Update 2

these numbers represent the estimated profit for a product

Comment: There is no single rule.  You look at the number and decide which scheme will produce the best comprehension (while still being efficient), taking into account the individuals listening and any noise in the environment.

Comment: (Out of the blue, for the above numbers, I would most likely just read the individual digits -- "one one two, one seven seven" -- pausing briefly after every three digits.  But especially a number with a lot of zeros (or even just identical digits like "111111") would tend to be treated differently, or at least more carefully.)

Comment: A lot depends on what these numbers represent.  Phone numbers are treated differently from population numbers which are treated differently from monetary values which are treated differently from product identification numbers.

Comment: Note that your examples are 6 digits, but your title says 5 digits.

Comment: For estimated profits one would rarely specify more than 3 decimal places of precision.  The first would be read as "122 thousand pounds", with "approximately" or "about" being added if one feels compelled to say that.

Comment: Nobody would read that first number *"eleven hundred thousand and twenty one hundred and seventy seven"*. And if somebody did, they wouldn't be understood.

Comment: In spoken English (British, American, or other), one may very often safely assume that numbers of this sort are precisely represented in some report, form, or register.  Speaking these numbers to all their digits of precision is therefore unhelpful and even obfuscating.  Better spoken representations for the 1st include *"just over one hundred ten thousand"*, and for the 2nd *"nearly two hundred thousand"*.

Comment: "eleven hundreds thousands" We don't pluralize when reading off an exact number.  I've said this dozens of times. :)

Comment: @Peter Especially because ‘eleven hundred thousand, twenty one hundred and twenty-seven’ is not 112,177, but 1,102,127.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*One hundred and twelve thousand, one hundred and seventy seven*.

*One hundered and ninety six thousand, four hundred and fifty five*.

The format is *...,xxx,yyy,zzz*.

For *zzz* you say the *z hundred* and whatever *zz* is (which has many exceptions).

For *yyy*, it's the same, but say *y thousand* instead of *z hundred*.

Beyond thousands, it's millions, billions, etc.

Comment: I agree, being British. But in my observation, Americans ususally omit all the "ands" from that.

Comment: Correct, Americans may drop the "ands" in there.  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/a/38032/9368